# Any reason chrono Time would be speeding up other than my code?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

a couple seconds into my game, everything speeds up. I cant find any problem with my code but there definitely could be one. I was wondering if its possible that my graphics card is kicking into high gear or something. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>    
#include "PongGame.h"

int main()
{

    PongGame game(10);
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1500, 900), "SFML works!");

    float UPDATE_INTERVAL = 900000000.0f;
    float lag = 0.0f;

    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Time;
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds ms;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<float> fsec;
    auto prevTime = Time::now();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        auto currTime = Time::now();
        fsec fs = currTime - prevTime;
        ms d = std::chrono::duration_cast<ms>(fs);
        lag += d.count();
        //std::cout << "lag1: " << lag << "\n";
        while (lag > UPDATE_INTERVAL) {
            std::cout << "loop";
            sf::Event currEvent;
            while (window.pollEvent(currEvent))
            {
                if (currEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed) { window.close(); }
            }
            game.PollKeys();
            game.Update(1.0f);
            game.Render(1.0f, &window);
            //lag -= UPDATE_INTERVAL;
            lag = 0;
            std::cout << "lag2: " << lag << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

@Howard Hinnant

I am now comparing everything in terms of chrono milliseconds. I've stepped through the code a good amount now and I just cant understand why it's accelerating like it is. Here is the new code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>    
#include "PongGame.h"

int main()
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock hiResTime;
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds ms;
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point time_point;

    PongGame game(10);
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1500, 900), "SFML works!");
    time_point prevTime = hiResTime::now();
    time_point currTime = hiResTime::now();
    const ms UPDATE_INTERVAL(99999999);
    ms lag(0);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        prevTime = currTime;
        time_point currTime = hiResTime::now();
        ms currInterval = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(currTime - prevTime);
        lag += currInterval;
        if (lag > UPDATE_INTERVAL) {
            //std::cout << "loop";
            sf::Event currEvent;

            if ((window.pollEvent(currEvent)) && (currEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed)) { window.close(); }
            game.PollKeys();
            game.Update(1.0f);
            game.Render(1.0f, &window);

            //lag -= UPDATE_INTERVAL;
            lag = ms(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what this is doing. Your `while (lag > UPDATE_INTERVAL)` is only ever executed once since you set `lag` to 0 every time.

Comment: lag used to get set to -= UPDATE_INTERVAL, I think the idea was to have it execute multiple times in a row if the code was lagging behind, hence the name. I set it to zero as a way to simplify the problem, thinking that maybe that value was building up over time or something. Most of this code is copy pasted from tutorials, which is why I was confident it was working, actually .

Comment: Instead of converting your chrono variables to scalars which control the loop timing, change the type of your loop controlling variables to chrono types.  Anything that resembles a time duration should be a `std::chrono::duration` type.

Comment: The general idea of this to to only execute the "Update" function once per UPDATE_INTERVAL amount of time has passed. but its happening much faster than that.

Comment: thanks, I'll try that right now. I wrote my previous comment before I saw this.

Comment: @Howard, its still accelerating really quickly and I have no idea whats causing it. I tried to follow your advice while simplifying it as much as I could. Not sure what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old version of your code, you forgot to update `prevTime`. In the current version, you still don’t do that as `currTime` in `prevTime = currTime;` is the one defined directly in `main()`, but it is never updated because `time_point currTime = hiResTime::now();` defines new variable with the same name (which is allowed because that’s in a nested block) instead of updating the previously defined one. So the first `currTime` always contains the game start time.

Comment: Oh god you're right. Ugh thats so emberassing. I guess I should delete my question then since it has nothing to do with std::chrono. Right?